# Remove duplicate remote syslog messages

Tags: syslog, fluentd, graylog2

For redundancy, every host in our distributed network sends its syslog messages to two dedicated `rsyslog`-nodes. These in turn send syslogs to a central `graylog` instance:

```
    / rsyslog \
host           --> graylog  
    \ rsyslog /
```

Now every log-message gets duplicated!

Question: How can we keep the redundancy but remove duplicates? Does `fluentd` have a way to deal with this? Or any other opensource software designed to aggregate log-messages?
We do not want to include much more complexity to the whole setup, but inserting one additional component is fine.

Answer (score 0):

AKAIK, there is no open source software which has built-in de-dup message because such requirements are application specific.
We may implement such message handling with master node but it has a performance / scalable problem.

We have several approaches to relax problem.

- Add unique id to record and distinct in queries. I don't know how to distinct in graylog...
- One stream is for realtime and another stream is for backup. No merge streams in one graylog
- On fluentd, you may use fluent-plugin-suppress(https://github.com/fujiwara/fluent-plugin-suppress) or fluent-plugin-dedup(https://github.com/edvakf/fluent-plugin-dedup) for such cases.